# The derivative of $u^\top N\, x$ with respect to $u$

Tags: partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, control-theory

How do I find the following derivative:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(u^\top N\, x)
$$

Where $u$ and $x$ are vectors of variables and $N$ is a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

I went through and broke the matrices and vectors into components and did the derivation.

I found that it equals $N x$

Comment: Often the convention of a partial derivative would be that it would return a row vector of the partial derivatives of the expression with respect to each variable in $u$. If you would follow that convention you would actually need to take the transpose of your answer.